# how to render item always on top in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I have a card inside the flatlist. When the user post something than card is rendered. But the card randomly fits in view. I want to render that card on the top of the screen, each time user post something. (like facebook, insta, twitter)
I need help

Comment: Are you talking about a Toast UI element ?

Comment: Yeah kind off..

Comment: Not sure what you mean by randomly fits into view? and what do you mean by top of the screen? Is it floating at the top? or top of a list? or z-index "top of screen" ?

Comment: I fixed it. thanks for the opinion. actually i am using firebase and my condition is like when you post something on facebook than that post appears on top of the timeline page,how that appears always on top.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what your looking for but, if you want a component to always be on top, you can use `zIndex`:

```
<IconButton
    aria-label="Toggle mobile menu"
    icon={<Hamburger />}
    display={{ base: "inline-block", md: "none" }}
    onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)}
    zIndex={9999} // <--- this will keep the component always on top
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague

1. **For displaying the latest post as the first item in a list**, similar to a fresh tweet or post on Instagram. To implement this, you can easily use the `unshift` method to add new data to the beginning of the list:

```
//...

const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);

const addPost = () => {
  //...

  const newData = data;
  /**
   * shift the current data and putting on new post as first
   */
  newData.unshift(newPost);
  /**
   * update the data state
   */
  setData(newData);
};

//...
```

And new data will render as first item.

More info about `unshift`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift

2. **If you want to render a different component at the top of the list**, you can place it in the `ListHeaderComponent` prop of the `FlatList` component. When necessary, such as for a new post, you can update the data accordingly, show/hide, etc. (Alternatively, you can place it outside the `FlatList` component, at the top, to keep it fixed and prevent the user from scrolling on it)